# How to swap struct elements of array inside a struct - C

Tags: c, struct, swap, items

I have 2 structs

```
typedef struct {
    int i;
    int p;
} item;

typedef struct {
    item items[10];
} buffer;

void swap (item** p1, item** p2) {
   item* temp = *p1;
  *p1 = *p2;
  *p2 = temp;
}
```

im trying to call

```
    item *ps = &buffer.items[0];
    item *p = &buffer.items[1];

    swap(&ps, &p);
```

but it is not swapping them? What am I doing wrong? Thanks
would there be any change if the struct buffer was local in main or global?

Thanks

Comment: In swap(), the code is taking the swapping pointers, not the end int values.  Perhaps the intent is to swap the int values not the pointers?

Comment: Code does not compile even if issues with `swap` are solved: `buffer` is not variable, but `typedef`. `buffer.items` is thus illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function only swaps the *pointers* `ps` and `p`, not the actual structures they point to. For that you need to copy the structures, something like

```
void swap (item* p1, item* p2) {
   item temp = *p1;
  *p1 = *p2;
  *p2 = temp;
}
```

Call as

```
swap(&buffer.items[0], &buffer.items[1]);
```

Comment: if it is an array of char* why does it need to pass in a pointer to a pointer to swap the char * but not for a struct? Thanks e.g. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-strings-in-c/

Comment: @thebeginner Because then the data is a `char *`, not an `item`. You need to pass a pointer to the *element data type*, and if that data type is a pointer you pass a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap pointers but not structs!

```
item item0, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9;

typedef struct {
    item * items[10] =  { &item0, &item1, &item2, &item3, &item4, &item5, &item6, &item7, &item8, &item9 };
} buffer;

item **ps = &(buffer.items[0]);
item **p = &(buffer.items[1]);

swap(ps, p);
```

Answer (score 0):

i used an array of struct and swap them w/ a temp

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stddef.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct Ville{
    char name[25];
    long population;
}Ville;
Ville classerVille(Ville *p_list,int index);
int main(){
    Ville city_ranking[15];
    int number_of_city=0;
    strcpy(city_ranking[0].name,"Metz");
    city_ranking[0].population=11890;   
    number_of_city++;

    strcpy(city_ranking[1].name,"Nevers");
    city_ranking[1].population=33325;
    number_of_city++;

    strcpy(city_ranking[2].name,"Paris");
    city_ranking[2].population=2190327;
    number_of_city++;

    strcpy(city_ranking[3].name,"Reims");
    city_ranking[3].population=183113;
    number_of_city++;

    strcpy(city_ranking[4].name,"Lyon");
    city_ranking[4].population=515695;
    number_of_city++;

    classerVille(city_ranking,number_of_city);
    return 0;
}

Ville classerVille(Ville *p_list,int index){
    Ville temp;
    for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
        for(int j=i;j<index;j++){
            if(p_list[i].population>p_list[j].population){
                temp=p_list[i];
                p_list[i]=p_list[j];
                p_list[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return *p_list;
}
```